# How to make QCheckBox readonly, but not grayed-out

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox

Any good way to make a checkbox readonly, but also **not grayed-out** (hardly visible).

1. I have used `setEnabled(bool)` which works, but the checkbox then is grayed-out and hardly readable
2. I can react on a toggle signal and reset the state. But I would need a kind of flag to determine if the box is read-only and then reset the check state, means I need to create my own `CheckBox` class.
3. `setCheckable` does not work either, it does not allow me to set a checked state at all:

   ```
       cb = this->ui->cb_RealWorld->isCheckable();
       this->ui->cb_RealWorld->setCheckable(true);
       this->ui->cb_RealWorld->setChecked(someValue);
       this->ui->cb_RealWorld->setCheckable(cb);
   ```

So the best thing I have is to use enable/disable and accept the grayed out style.

------- Edit -------

Following the [stylesheet examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcheckbox) I was hoping I could set the style of a disabled checkbox like the one of an enabled. Failed so far to do so. More specific: Changing the icon like in the [examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcheckbox) does not work for me, maybe because I am using Windows and the icons are not available under the path as in the examples.

---

PS: Related, but no answer here

[Disabling a QCheckbox in a tricky way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8542123/356726)
[Qt - How to disable QCheckBox while retaining checked state?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24016264/356726)

Comment: What do you mean by 'read-only'? A check box doesn't record information but only the state of something.

Comment: Readonly: User can not change the checkbox state, like in QLineEdit where the use cannot change a readonly text

Comment: Btw, I do not understand the downvote. But never mind.

Comment: It is not useless. I have a form, which is either editable or readonly. The checkbox either displays true (checked) or false (unchecked). Where have I said it will always be checked (pls. let me know so I can fix that part).

Only authenticated users can modify the checkbox, but in readonly mode (anonymous users) still I want to display true or false. And I want to use a checkbox to display true/false, only I do not want it to be modified.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Following the below my code:

```
this->ui->cb_RealWorld->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
this->ui->cb_RealWorld->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

Comment: Thanks, just to add to this. You leave the checkbox as "enabled" and "checkable". This just makes it so the control ignores mouse events and can not have focus.

Answer (score 12):

This is Devopia's solution as a function:

```
void SetReadOnly(QCheckBox* checkBox, bool readOnly)
{
   checkBox->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, readOnly);
   checkBox->setFocusPolicy(readOnly ? Qt::NoFocus : Qt::StrongFocus);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, remember to `#include "windows.h"` and set flags as follows:

```
this->ui->cb_RealWorld->setWindowFlags(this->ui->cb_RealWorld->windowFlags() | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from QCheckBox and override nextCheckState method https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#nextCheckState do the trick.

```
void ReadOnlyCheckBox::nextCheckState()
{

}
```

Comment: Inspired by this, I derived my own checkbox class, added a `readOnly` property to it, then returning from above function if `readOnly` is set or calling `QCheckBox::nextCheckState()` if it is not