# Python 3: PyQt: Make checkbox disabled + not grayed out + display tooltip

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, pyqt4, disabled-control

The only way I found to do this is [here: How to make QCheckBox readonly, but not grayed-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190259/how-to-make-qcheckbox-readonly-but-not-grayed-out). This, however, disables mouse interactions with the control. But I need the tooltip to be displayed when mouse is over the control. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This seems a horrible thing to do from a ux pov, since it completely undermines the normal behaviour. What's the use-case?

Comment: If you don't need to have the checkbox not grayed out, you can disable it; the tooltip still displays for a disabled checkbox. I'm not sure how to make it disabled without graying it out

Comment: There's an option that I control somewhere else that I don't want to look gray. That's all. @PeterWang

Comment: There's an option that I control somewhere else that I don't want to look gray. That's all. @ekhumoro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this is what you'd be asking for, a disabled checkbox showing tooltips:

```
 import sys
 from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


 class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

      def __init__(self):
           super(Example, self).__init__()
           self.initUI()

      def initUI(self):
           self.cb = QtGui.QCheckBox('Disabled CheckBox showing tooltips', self)
           self.cb.move(20, 20)
           self.cb.toggle()
           # self.cb.setEnabled(False)
           # self.cb.setStyleSheet("color: black")
           # self.cb.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AlwaysShowToolTips)
           self.cb.setToolTip ('my checkBox')
           self.cb.toggled.connect(self.prevent_toggle)

           self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 50)
           self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QCheckBox')
           self.show()

      def prevent_toggle(self):
           self.cb.setChecked(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

 def main():
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      ex = Example()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())


 if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: You missed the part "not grayed out"... I want it disabled without being gray.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Ok, I've missed that part indeed. I've edited my answer, that way you'd have it "not grayed out"

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Do you mean the tickbox's gray?

Comment: Yes. The gray because the checkbox is disabled.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Ok, I've edited my answer again, this time should satisfy all your requirements

Comment: @BPL - Can you explain how this works? It took me a bit to realize what you were doing and I suspect the viewers at home might not get it right away either...

Answer (score 2):

```
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.

self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
self.checkBox.setEnabled (False)
self.checkBox.setToolTip ('my checkBox')
```

Comment: Sorry. This is so not what I want. I definitely know disabled, and that's why I asked for "not grayed out".